# Installing MT4 Server

Tags: windows, https

I installed Meta Trader 4 service to my development machine for testinmg purposes, opened task manager's **Services** tab and tried to start **mtsrv**. But the sevice didn't started succesfully. In the logs (C:\MetaTrader4Server\logs\20120618.txt) I see the following log:

> 4 16:33:46        Startup: port 443 is busy

I closed Skype, teamviewer etc and tried again, but the result is not succesfull.

[image]

What do I have to do to run mt4 service succesfully in my machine?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you have IIS installed on the machine??

Comment: Yes @ChrisS? Is it because of IIS?

Comment: Yes it was. I stopped IIS and it worked fine. If you want you can write it as an answer, so I can mark it as an answer.